# Image uploaded with Laravel not found in the public folder images

Tags: php, laravel

Hi am working on a laravel project trying to upload user profile image but can not be found in public images.

below is my Users table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('organization');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->binary('avatar')->default('/images/default.png');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

And below is my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'organization', 'location', 'email', 'password','avatar',
       
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

The belew is my Register.blade.php file where am trying to save the file

```
                    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="card-text"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo1.jpg') }}" width="60" height="50" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="logo1"></p>
        <hr style="width:50%", size="2", color=3490dc>
            <div class="card">
            <div style="text-align: center; background-color:#3490dc; color:white;" class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ __('Sign up') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                       <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="organization" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-building-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Organization') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="organization" type="text" class="form-control @error('organization') is-invalid @enderror" name="organization" value="{{ old('organization') }}" required autocomplete="organization" autofocus>

                                @error('organization')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="location" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Location') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="location" type="text" class="form-control @error('location') is-invalid @enderror" name="location" value="{{ old('location') }}" placeholder="Country,City,Area" required autocomplete="location" autofocus>

                                @error('location')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="avatar" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-upload" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Upload image') }}<br/>
                            <span class="small-text text-info">* not required</span>
                        </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control @error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror" name="avator">

                                @error('avatar')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-key" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-key" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

RegisterController where i am trying to save the file in my images directory in public folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'organization' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'location' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'avatar' => ['sometimes', 'image', 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,bmp,svg|max:5048'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if(request()->has('avatar'))
        {
            $avataruploaded = request()->file('avatar');
            $avatarname = time() . '.' . $avataruploaded->getcilentOriginalExtension();
            $avatarpath = public_path('/images/');
            $avataruploaded->move($avatarpath, $avatarname);
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'organization' => $data['organization'],
                'location' => $data['location'],
                'avatar' => '/images/' . $avatarname,
               'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
        }
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'organization' => $data['organization'],
            'location' => $data['location'],
           'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The file looks like it is being saved somewhere else where i can`t fetch it in my blade view.
I will appreciate any help thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is the URL you are using in your HTML for the image?

Comment: Did you link your storage? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I think that you didnt link your storage my friend. Check @DanielL answer

Comment: linking storage is not necessary since you don't intend to store the image in the storage folder.  dd the `$avatarPath` in the controller and check what it says

Comment: Hi @lagbox this is the URL i am using in my HTML...<img src="{{ asset('auth()->user()->avatar') }}" alt="">

Comment: and what **URL** does that generate?